# JBoss and Quartz

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, classloader, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to see if Quartz can solve a problem for me. But I can't get it to work. Right now I'm stuck at the following error (relevant part)

```
    Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Unable to instantiate class load helper class: org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper cannot be cast to org.quartz.spi.ClassLoadHelper [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper cannot be cast to org.quartz.spi.ClassLoadHelper]
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:706)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1484)
    at org.jboss.seam.async.QuartzDispatcher.initScheduler(QuartzDispatcher.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper cannot be cast to org.quartz.spi.ClassLoadHelper
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:703)
```

I have googled and it seems to be a question that is asked a lot but I don't find any answers. I have the quartz-jars in both my webapp and ear.

Is there anything in my configuration that can cause this problem?

JBoss 5.1
Quartz JBoss 2.1.6

Comment: quartz is already bundled up with jboss, you might find it within quartz-ra.rar in your jboss deployment. This is by the looks of your error log, a class mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a class loading issue. JBoss already has the `org.quartz.spi.ClassLoadHelper.class` in its class path since JBoss uses it for internal timers for different tasks. The JBoss provided `quartz.jar` is located in `/jboss-as/common/lib/quartz.jar` . So you are providing another `quartz.jar` with your application which is causing conflict with the existing quartz classes that is provided with JBoss.

To solve this issue you have two options:

- **Option 1**. Remove the quartz jars from your ear and war. This is the better and easier option in my opinion unless for some reason you need a different version of quartz for your application than the one JBoss provides.
- **Option 2**. Create a `META-INF\jboss-classloading.xml` file and isolate your ear (and may be your WAR `WEB-INF\jboss-classloading.xml` if there is a need for the EAR classes to not see WAR classes). This [blog](http://phytodata.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/demystifying-the-jboss5-jboss-classloading-xml-file/) is one of the good ones at explaining the jboss5 or jboss6 class loading and this [tutorial based blog](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-configuration/solving-jboss-5-classloading-issues) is also a good resource.