# Cannot Cast CascadingClassLoadHelper to Quartz ClassLoadHelper

Tags: java, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, jbossfuse

I'm getting the following exception while trying to deploy my camel-quartz application in fuse:

```
Application context refresh failed (OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=test-quartz-impl, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml))
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route371: Route(route371)[[From[quartz://test/testQuartzJob?c... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: quartz://test/testQuartzJob?cron=0+0%2F15+*+1%2F1+*+%3F due to: Cannot auto create component: quartz
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1619)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:123)[210:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:332)[210:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:96)[174:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:3.2.12.RELEASE_2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)[174:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:3.2.12.RELEASE_2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950)[174:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:3.2.12.RELEASE_2]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractOsgiBundleApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractOsgiBundleApplicationContext.java:235)[178:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:358)[178:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)[178:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)[178:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)[179:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_121]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route371: Route(route371)[[From[quartz://test/testQuartzJob?c... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: quartz://test/testQuartzJob?cron=0+0%2F15+*+1%2F1+*+%3F due to: Cannot auto create component: quartz
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:190)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:838)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:2897)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:2620)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:167)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2469)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2465)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2488)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2465)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2434)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:255)[210:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:121)[210:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: quartz://test/testQuartzJob?cron=0+0%2F15+*+1%2F1+*+%3F due to: Cannot auto create component: quartz
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:575)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:79)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:200)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:107)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:113)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.model.FromDefinition.resolveEndpoint(FromDefinition.java:70)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.getEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:89)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1008)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:185)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Cannot auto create component: quartz
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getComponent(DefaultCamelContext.java:397)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getComponent(DefaultCamelContext.java:373)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:545)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Unable to instantiate class load helper class: org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper cannot be cast to org.quartz.spi.ClassLoadHelper [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper cannot be cast to org.quartz.spi.ClassLoadHelper]
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:692)[662:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz:1.8.6.1]
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1509)[662:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz:1.8.6.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzComponent.createScheduler(QuartzComponent.java:555)[664:org.apache.camel.camel-quartz:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzComponent.getScheduler(QuartzComponent.java:407)[664:org.apache.camel.camel-quartz:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzComponent.doStart(QuartzComponent.java:228)[664:org.apache.camel.camel-quartz:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:2871)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getComponent(DefaultCamelContext.java:392)[205:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621117]
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper cannot be cast to org.quartz.spi.ClassLoadHelper
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:689)[662:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz:1.8.6.1]
    ... 39 more
```

I am using camel-quartz (Quartz1 of camel).
I've seen this [JBoss and Quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455460/jboss-and-quartz) but it is specific to JBoss server.

Comment: can you add a list of your dependencies? probably you have some version conflict.

Answer (score 1):

The camel-quartz dependency didn't have any scope.
After checking here http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-extra-camel-componets-in-servicemix-camel.html, I've added provided and it started working.
Thank You @nmagerko and @ledniov.